# Total values of makes some litter difference how can i get exact value in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
Speed   A   b       c                        Total
129     11  4   2.75                         354.75
91       9  6   1.5                          136.5
166     19  8   2.375                        395.08
164     26  12  2.16666666666667             355.88
146     11  6   1.83333333333333             267.18
147     16  8   2                            294
201     8   3   2.66666666666667             536.67
164     4   2   2                            328
186     8   6   1.33333333333333             247.38
165     7   4   1.75                         288.75
171    10   4   2.5                          427.5
104    5    4   1.25                         130
1834  134   67  2                            3668
```

Iam using total=Speed*c
But   the value is not getting equal if i add all values for last column 1834 .I am getting 100 ampunt less.

Comment: Dear, 164 * 2.166666667 is 355,3333333....

Answer (score 0):

The first:

`Total = Speed * c`, this expression about your output I suppose is rounded at the second number after comma.

The second:

You have put 2 as value of `c` in the last row. Why? This is the average of all previous rows?

So, if you take  the forst and the second, you'll have cause about you have a difference with the last row and the other rows

Comment: if you add total of all rows except last row the totals must euqal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. 
Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in the data
type range can be represented exactly.
```

Float has a default 15 digit precision. So when your number has more digits it will round off the rest of the digits.

You are showing total with only 2 decimals. You could consider permanently changing c to decimal(20,14). Here is the result if you convert it to decimal, this should be more exact:

```
select cast(c as decimal(20, 14)) * speed as Total
from table
```